# php printing out arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays, matrix

Im working with an array, i have opened it up and started to work on printing it out with this code...

```
<html>
<?php
$file=fopen("curr_enroll_fall.csv", "r");
$records[]=fgetcsv($file);
print_r($records);
?>
</html>
```

This gives me this output...

```
Array ( [0] => Array (  [0] => Subj 
                        [1] => # 
                        [2] => Title 
                        [3] => Comp Numb 
                        [4] => Sec 
                        [5] => Lec Lab 
                        [6] => Camp Code 
                        [7] => Max Enrollment 
                        [8] => Current Enrollment 
                        [9] => Start Time 
                        [10] => End Time 
                        [11] => Days 
                        [12] => Credits 
                        [13] => Bldg 
                        [14] => Room 
                        [15] => Instructor 
                        [16] => NetId 
                        [17] => Email 
                    ) 
    )
```

I would like to be able to print out all of the items under a certain header like for example print out all the Titles. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Use `$records = fgetcsv($file);`

Comment: `fgetscv()` reads one row at a time, so you have to do it in a loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly how would that be done?

Comment: Well first you need to [Read `fgetcsv()` the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) Then you write some code. Then you test it. Then you fix any errors...... repeat until you get what you want **SO != Free coding service** We help fix, we dont write it for you

Comment: @user6806552 The manual has lots of examples.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i added this code while(!feof($file)){
        $records[]=fgetcsv($file);
    }

Comment: Read the examples in the manual. Click the link I gave you. It is in many languages if English is not your first language

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$handle = fopen("curr_enroll_fall.csv", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
   printf( '%s <br />', $data[2] );
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Why not use printf() function - printf( '%s <br />', $data[2] ); its more beautiful.

Comment: Just because you asked for it @Frager. ;)